A movie about a white woman managing black farmers on a farmland, where her father's arrival leads to a violent assault
I'm trying to identify an English-language movie. In it, a daughter lives by a farmland. She might have some kind of contract with the farmers who work for her. The farmers are black, and the owner is a white woman. She is alone there in the beginning.
Later, her dad arrives; he is a white man. The father is beaten by black males who rape the daughter. After a while, the father figures out who those males were and wants to get into action, but the daughter disagrees, and the father comes to know this happened even before.

I figured out the name using the website whatismymovie.com this will save all your hard work you put on marking this and that.the name of the movie is disgrace (2008) if someone else asks about the same movie

Disgrace (2008)
Based on anil's (the OP) 2017 comment, the described movie is Disgrace (2008), directed by Steve Jacobs and based on the novel by J.M. Coetzee. The film stars John Malkovich as David Lurie, a white professor who finds himself in a tumultuous personal and moral crisis after a series of events unfold in post-apartheid South Africa.
In the movie, Lucy (Jessica Haines) lives on a farm in the Eastern Cape of South Africa, which matches the description of a daughter living by farmland. Her father David comes to stay with her after facing professional difficulties.
Movie plot:

David Lurie (John Malkovich) is an ageing white professor teaching Romantic literature at an unnamed university in Cape Town shortly after the end of apartheid. David has an affair with one of his students, Melanie Isaacs (Antoinette Engel). University officials learn of the incident and bring David before a disciplinary board. David's colleagues offer him a quiet exit to save face, but he brashly affirms his guilt and refuses to admit wrongdoing, forcing the board to punish him more harshly.
David takes refuge with his daughter, Lucy (Jessica Haines), who owns a farm in the Eastern Cape. At first, the two experience harmony and Lurie finds peace with himself, though he grows suspicious of Lucy's farm manager, Petrus (Eriq Ebouaney). One day, David and Lucy are attacked by three men, who rape Lucy. David goes through a crisis, not knowing how to cope with his personal and family tragedies. He is also confused by the newfound guilt he suddenly feels about these rapes. In a movement toward penance, David goes back to his former student's home to beg for forgiveness from her and her family.
After a brief sojourn in Cape Town, he returns to the farm to find that Lucy is pregnant and that Petrus is steadily increasing his control over the property. One of the rapists has taken up residence with Petrus, and turns out to be his brother-in-law. Despite David's outrage, Lucy insists on not taking the matter to the authorities, and states that she will bear the child. Petrus offers to "marry" her and she agrees in order to come under his protection. David must come to terms with the new South Africa.

